# Selenium Webdriver: Automatically Repeating a successful scenario

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I use Selenium Webdriver tests based on Java/Gherkin/Cucumber.

I have a test running that I want to run multiple times, without me having to restart the scenario several times.

The Gherkin script is something like this:

```
Given the user opens a browser
Then the user fills in the form
Then the user repeats the filling of the form *5* times
```

This way, if I want 10 forms to be filled in, I can just replace the 5 with 10, press play, and grab a beer.

Is this at all possible or do I just have to re-run the scenario manually 5 times?

Comment: you can use loop and can pass all form URLs in that..so it will take one by one and perform.

Comment: Is the form being populated with the same field data each time?

Comment: @ Ben smith: Aye, no difference there

Comment: why dont use a loop for that in your step definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could simplify a bit your Gherkin scenario, like:

```
 Given the user opens a browser

 Then the user fills in the form 5 times
```

Taking this scenario you then generate your methods and in the second method you can add a loop, like:

[Then(@"the user fills in the form (.*) times")]

```
public void ThenTheUserFillsInTheForm(int nrOfTimes)   
{        
    for(int i = 0; i < nrOfTimes; i++)
    {

      //user fills in the form

    }
}
```